How to get backoff duration before next retry in project reactor?
I'm looking for a way to get how long the backoff duration before retrying when using retries in Project Reactor 3.6+. Project Reactor has a utility library called reactor-extra which I've previously used to achieve this:
var myFlux = Flux.of(...)
myFlux.retry(Retry
            .anyOf(TimeoutException.class)
            .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(1), Duration.ofSeconds(5)).retryMax(5)
            .doOnRetry(ctx -> {
                var e = (TimeoutException) ctx.exception();
                var secondsToWaitBeforeNextRetry = ctx.backoff().seconds
                log.info("Will retry again in roughly {} s", secondsToWaitBeforeNextRetry);
            })
)

While this works fine, the Retry class in reactor.retry has been deprecated for a while and the javadocs says that one should use reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec instead. The problem is that I can't seem to find the equivalent of ctx.backoff().seconds when using this approach. Here's my attempt at converting the previous example into the more modern approach:
var myFlux = Flux.of(...)
myFlux.retryWhen(RetryBackoffSpec.backoff(5, Duration.ofSeconds(1)).maxBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .filter(TimeoutException.class::isAssignableFrom)
                .doBeforeRetry(signal -> {
                    var e = (TimeoutException) signal.exception();
                    var secondsToWaitBeforeNextRetry = // TODO What to write here?
                    log.info("Will retry again in roughly {} s", secondsToWaitBeforeNextRetry);
                })
)

Is there a built-in way to get how long it'll take before the next retry attempt that is not deprecated?
